# Where exactly is the onClick method of OnclickListener interface called inside the Android system when we click the button?

Tags: android, view, onclicklistener

I am new to Android and I went through the view.Java file in Android. But the methods inside this file are not clear and I want to know where the code for setting the OnclickListener is? where the onClick method is actually called?

Comment: You don't have to go through view.java files, they're too messy and hard to understand. You can go to https://developer.android.com/ and they have all methods listed. Or you can watch some youtube tutorials.

Comment: The click listener's `onClick()` is called by `performClick()`, which is called by `performClickInternal()`, which is called by `onTouchEvent()` and `onKeyUp()` when taps or keyboard presses should be interpreted as a view click. It goes on and on back from where the system handles input events and passes them on down to views in the hierarchy. This is all encapsulated so you don't have to know about it.

Comment: It made most of the things clear to me. Thanks a lot

Comment: I would also like to know that , when we see the SetOnclickListener method in view.java it accepts View.OnclickListener parameter. But this parameter is never assigned to the class variable. Why is this so?

Answer (score 2):

First, give the button in your XML layout file an ID. For example I will call it "btn".
Then in your Java file, write this:
`Button button=findViewById(R.id.btn);`
This will make the system know that when you call "button", you mean the button with ID called "btn" in XML file.

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view){
        //Insert what you want to do when button is clicked
    }
});
```

Tip: when you are typing, Android Studio will show suggestions. So if you type "button." and haven't finished typing setOnClickListener, it will show you a menu, then you can choose setOnClickListener(). It will save you a lot of time. 
Also, inside `setOnClickListener()` parentheses, type `new Vie` and Android Studio will already show you suggestion `new View.setOnClickListener`, and all the @Override part is done for you.

Comment: actually i was asking the internal working of the onClickListener

Answer (score 2):

```
    /**
 * Register a callback to be invoked when this view is clicked. If this view is not
 * clickable, it becomes clickable.
 *
 * @param l The callback that will run
 *
 * @see #setClickable(boolean)
 */
public void setOnClickListener(@Nullable OnClickListener l) {
    if (!isClickable()) {
        setClickable(true);
    }
    getListenerInfo().mOnClickListener = l;
}
```

*@Raghav: "I would also like to know that , when we see the SetOnclickListener method in view.java it accepts View.OnclickListener parameter. But this parameter is never assigned to the class variable. Why is this so?"*

To answer that, it is in fact assigned. If you see in the given code snippet from **View.java**, the instance of implementing class that you pass to **setOnClickListener()** from your **mainActivity.java** is received/stored in the ***OnClickListener 'l'*** formal parameter as mentioned by the doc comments above the code. That is then assigned to **mOnClickListener** (also can be seen in the code snippet).